# what is the recommended workflow to bulk replace images in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import, export, bulkupdate

I know my workflow is wrong because it shouldn't be this tedious.

**What I want to update?**

- Products images
- Alt and Caption

**What I have done**

- I can't find a way to bulk replace media images, I have to do them one by one using a plugin.
- I have to manually key in the alt and caption one by one (there is a bulk edit alt plugin but I need the alt tag to be different for each image, so it doesn't apply to my needs in this case)

The above is a painstaking manual onerous process. I did all the above in a staging environment as recommended by the wordpress community.

After updating the staging site, I assumed importing and exporting the products and images to the production site will be swift. But no....

**Update Production Website**

- I use Products > All Products > Export / Import, it doesn't work as anticipated. It doesn't update but add the products as new.
- I use wordpress importer, it failed to import the media files.
- It also seems that I have to redo the entire process of updating alt, caption and description again on the production environment.

I do not want to use migration plugin because the staging website has lots of unnecessary posts, images, content that i don't want to move to the production site.

What's the recommended workflow to do the above? I have already updated the staging site. How can I update the production site without going through the same process again?

Thanks.